# Bootsrap carousel navigation doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Images do not scroll, and when I inspect my page I don't find any errors. This is the head of my HTML file:

```
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-
1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-
theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l
/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: You have whitespace in one `href` and both `integrity` attributes. I'd start by removing that.

Comment: make a snippet or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this *code*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EvzEpEi.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VzV3NwJ.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zQIlCOu.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
```

snippet